# JSF - h:selectOneMenu Setter is never called

Tags: java, jsf

Cant understand `<h:selectOneMenu>` component. Tried many ways to pass parameter from dropdown to java, and 4 different ways to call java method. First two ways (onchange and commandbutton doesnt call java) other two does, but works badly as it cant set selectedItem to java variable:

```
<h:form id="tasks">

    <h:selectOneMenu id = "selectonemenu" value="#{services.selectedItem}"
    immediate="true" onchange="javascript: return this.form.submit();">
        <f:selectItems value="#{services.selectItems}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:commandButton value = "StringHello" action="#{services.StringHelo}" />

    <s:link action="#{services.StringHello}" reRender="tasks"></s:link>

    <a:commandLink id="aclink"
                                action="#{services.StringHello}"
                                ajaxSingle="true" eventsQueue="globalQueue"
                                ignoreDupResponses="true" requestDelay="0"
                                onComplete="return false;"
                                status="globalStatus">
                                aclink
                                </a:commandLink>
    <h:outputText id = "valueofselected" value = "#{services.selectedItem}"/>
</h:form>
```

And Services.Java:

```
private String selectedItem;

public String getSelectedItem() {
    if (selectedItem == null) {
        selectedItem = "All"; // This will be the default selected item.
    }
    System.out.println("getSelectedItem "+selectedItem);
    return selectedItem;
}

public void setSelectedItem(String selectedItem) {
    this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
    System.out.println("setSelectedItem");
}

public List getSelectItems() {
    List selectItems = new ArrayList();
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem("All", "All"));
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem("A", "A"));
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem("B", "B"));
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem("C", "C"));
    selectItems.add(new SelectItem("D", "D"));
  System.out.println("getSelectItems: "+selectItems.size());
    return selectItems;
}
public void StringHello(){
    System.out.println(" SelectedItem - "+selectedItem);
}
```

returns null in console:

```
14:41:51,897 INFO  [STDOUT]  SelectedItem - null
```

but i can see that outputText's value is always "All" and in console i see every time when getSelectedItem method is called:

`14:41:49,087 INFO  [STDOUT] getSelectedItem All`

Also, i think it's very important: after i choose any value, page refreshes and it becomes default 'All' value again.

Comment: Probably you're using a wrong scope; we cannot see because you cut out that part from the bean definition.

Comment: yes, i found out that i use wrong Scope, it should be "SESSION" instead of current "STATELESS". But i can't change ScopeType to SESSION, because it causes many other errors in my code.

Comment: is there any way to combine? now i have @Scope(ScopeType.STATELESS)

Comment: @ujulu how can i set to java variables while it is stateless scope?

Comment: Edit the  Services.java and add  the rest of the header; otherwise I cannot see what you are doing.

Comment: @ujulu > can you tell me what can i add? im not good in seam annotations, that's what i have now: @ BypassInterceptors
@ SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@ Scope(ScopeType.STATELESS)
public class Services {

Comment: @ujulu Now, i've created separate Java file for that, and changed Scope to SESSION. But still i Set method is never called, according to console log

Comment: You haven't mentioned about Seam. I thought you're using JSF with CDI beans (JSF 2.0 or later). I haven't worked with Seam and cannot help you. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ujulu was right, i created separate java class with `@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)` and my form was located at wrong place, i moved it higher in hierarchy, to get rid of any parent components. And it works now.

Comment: So next time you create a real [mcve] upfront so everthing is directly visible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to send the whole form (do a form submit)?

Try this, there should be no page refresh:

```
<h:form id="tasks">

    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{services.selectedItem}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{services.selectItems}" />
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="result"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:outputText id="result" value="#{services.selectedItem}"/>
</h:form>
```